# jQuery loop through table cells and get the info for the one with lowest price

Tags: jquery, function

I kinda got stuck, if any one can give me a little push so I can move forward.

This is my code

```
function lowestPrice() {
    var lowestCost = 0;
    $('.cheapest a').click(function() {

        $('.typeCell').each(function() {
            if($(this).text().trim() == 'Sale') {
                var price = $(this).parent().find('.priceCell').text().trim();

                if(price < lowestCost) {
                    lowestCost = price;
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is my HTML. The idea is when I loop every prices from type "Sale" to print the info of that with the lowest one.

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Big House
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      1000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      2009
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Castle
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      500 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      2005
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Playboy Mansion
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent/Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      50 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      2000
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Adam's Family
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent/Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      100 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      1996
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Tom &amp; Jerry
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      2000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      1992
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Simpsons
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      1000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      1999
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      White House
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      1 000 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      1865
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Outside Agency
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      300 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      2011
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Mall Varna
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent/Sale
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      30 000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      2007
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="nameCell">
      Spooky House
    </td>
    <td class="typeCell">
      Rent
    </td>
    <td class="priceCell">
      1000
    </td>
    <td class="yearCell">
      1967
    </td>
    <td class="descriptionCell">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
      tempor
    </td>
    <span class="removeRow">
    </span>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: show us your html please

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I've added my HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make these two changes:

Initialize the `lowestCost` variable with a very high value, for example:

```
var lowestCost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
```

Convert the `price` to a number, for example:

```
var priceString = $(this).parent().find('.priceCell').text().trim();
var price = parseFloat(priceString);
```

---

The code can look like this:

```
function lowestPrice() {
    var lowestCost = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    var lowestCostRow;
    $('.typeCell').each(function() {
        if($(this).text().trim() == 'Sale') {
            var priceString = $(this).parent().find('.priceCell').text().trim();
            var price = parseFloat(priceString);
            if(price < lowestCost) {
                lowestCost = price;
                lowestCostRow = $(this).parent();
            }
        }
    });
    return lowestCostRow;
}
```

I think `click` shouldn't be inside the function.

Comment: yeah but how do I return the row that holds the lowest price

Comment: how do you need to return that row? as an alert message? or inside other element?

Comment: Yeah ok, but I dont't need to return "the lowest Price is ...." I need to return the whole row Name,type,price,year,description. I need to get the row that holds the lowest price cell and return it, not just the variable lowestCost

Comment: I was able to find the solution thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a different logic. As you loop thru all the prices from the tables, push() them into an array. Then you have all the control you need to find the lowest, highest, sorting etc.

You will know which element holds the price you want by the index of the array relative to the index of the table element that holds the price.